# Material-UI v5 Dialog exit fade animation not working with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm editing the React Router Modal Gallery example from their [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/modal-gallery) to include Material-UI [dialogs](https://next.material-ui.com/components/dialogs/). The problem is the exit animation (fade out) does not run because the URL changes as you close the modal, so it just disappears.

Is there a way to retain the current functionality and add the pleasant fade out?

[image: Edit React Router - Modal Gallery w/ Material-UI v5 Dialogs]

What I need is very similar to [this](https://sin9k.com/custom-prompt/sign-up), but when you refresh the page on that example, the modal is still open, I need it to open without the modal on page refresh, just like in the codesandbox and default React Router example.

*Note: this issue is not specific to Mui5, I just happen to be using it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is what you want and not sure if it is the best approach.

You can manipulate the transition manually and do whatever you want when the animation is done via `onExited()` method.

```
const Transition = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    // use Slide to display a clearer transition,
    // can replace it with Fade
    <Slide
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
      // do something after animation exited
      onExited={() => {
        history.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
});

function Modal(props) {
  // open state is used for transition trigger
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(props.open);

  const { id } = useParams();
  const image = IMAGES[parseInt(id, 10)];

  if (!image) return null;

  function handleClose() {
    // setting false to trigger exit animation
    setOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      TransitionComponent={Transition}
      scroll="body"
    >
      <Content />
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Here is the [codesandbox for demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-modal-gallery-w-material-ui-v5-dialogs-forked-lw2pg?file=/example.js:3013-3857).

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted, thank you! sorry if i wasnt clear. the title of this question could be 'how to properly use TransitionComponent in Material-UI v5' ‍♂️